# Run a macro only if the username matches the list

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to run a macro based on a condition of usernames, where do I make the changes:

for ex: 
I have the following dataset with usernames:

```
data users2; 
input name$; 
    cards; 
    ABC
    DEF
    YUT
    GTR
    ; 
run;
```

I have a macro to call: %callmacro;

```
proc sql; 
select name into: usernames separated by ',' from users2; 
quit;
```

so I call the macro

```
%macro NEW(); 
%if &sysuserid in (&usernames) %then %do;
%callmacro;
%end;
%mend;


%new;
```

So here I get an error :

```
ERROR: Required operator not found in expression: ( "&sysuserid" in 
(&usernames))
```

I would like to run a macro only if the username matches in the list. Else is there any way I can call a WINDOWS AD group from SAS macro and check if the sysuserid exixts in that Windows AD group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the usernames inside the macro

```
%macro ThisIsConditionallyRestricted(nametable=users2);
  proc sql noprint;
    select name from &nametable where name = "&sysuserid";
  quit;
  %if &SQLOBS = 0 %then %do;
    %put WARNING: You were not prepared!;
    %return;
  %end;
  … 
%mend;

%ThisIsConditionallyRestricted;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `in` statement in `%if` clause without special option. There are two ways to solve the problem.

**1.** `/minoperator` **option**(you need change delimeter in `&usernames` from `','` to `' '`. ):

Firstly, you need to change delimeter in `usernames` macro variable and use `strip` function:

```
proc sql; 
select strip(name) into: usernames separated by ' ' from users2; 
quit;
```

Then, your code with option `/minoperator`.

```
%macro new() /minoperator; 
   %if &sysuserid in (&usernames) %then %do;
      %callmacro;
   %end;
%mend;

%new;
```

**2. The other solution is to use loop by** `scan` **function**(no need in changing delimeter):

```
%macro new();
   %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(%bquote(&usernames),%str(%,)));
      %if %sysfunc(strip(%str(&sysuserid)))=%sysfunc(strip(%scan(%bquote(&usernames),&i,%str(%,)))) %then %do;
         %callmacro;
      %end;
   %end;
%mend new;


%new();
```

> Don't forget to use `strip` function, when you compare character
>   variables and `select into`. My advise is to change it:
>
> ```
> proc sql; 
> select strip(name) into: usernames separated by ',' from users2; 
> quit;
> ```

Comment: I prefer Richard's answer. Comparing text strings is fraught with problems. Your first and third solutions look sounds but the second one has the problem that if SYSUSERID is 'FRED', and your list of usernames contains 'FREDDY' but not 'FRED', the macro will still be executed.